# Format of the <version> string for installing a specific version of Docker Community Edition yum CentOS

Tags: linux, docker, centos, yum

I understand how to install the latest version of Docker CE and I understand almost completely how to install a specific version of Docker as I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981811/1258525) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/centos/) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/752207/install-specific-version-of-a-yum-pacakge-or-default-to-latest-via-environment-v)

My problem is that I cannot figure out the format of the version string `docker-ce-<version>` for installing a specific version of Docker Community Edition. I have tried:

```
yum install docker-ce-17.06
```

And

```
yum install docker-ce-17.06.0
```

And

```
yum install docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos
```

I get No package docker-ce- available messages like so:

```
No package docker-ce-17-06.0.ce-1.el7.centos available.
```

I ran

```
yum list docker-ce.x86_64  --showduplicates | sort -r
```

Output:

```
 * updates: centos.chicago.waneq.com
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Installed Packages
 * extras: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
 * epel: mirror.oss.ou.edu
docker-ce.x86_64            17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            17.03.1.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce.x86_64            17.03.1.ce-1.el7.centos            @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64            17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos            docker-ce-stable 
 * base: mirror.umd.edu
Available Packages
```

And I want to install Docker Community Edition 17.06.0

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was a typo in my version, here is what worked for me on CentOS 7:

```
yum install docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos
```

Answer (score 0):

For detailed answer of Installing specific or old version of Docker on Centos7 or later versions.

follow this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/65862402/5968928